# XF86Refresh Doesn't Map Correctly in Chrome

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome

I have one of my keys mapped to XF86Refresh which I confirmed with `xev`. In Firefox and Epiphany pressing the key works as expected, but in Chrome it acts like `CTRL + F`. Here's what `xev` says:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
root 0x173, subw 0x3c00002, time 6983238, (27,11), root:(898,478),
state 0x0, keycode 69 (keysym 0x1008ff29, XF86Refresh), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

[Video showing issue](https://gfycat.com/SecondhandDizzyHapuku)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First... I don't know how to map keys, never needed it. You should write the next time detailed info of what you did.

Now...

Why you use `XF86Refresh`?

I've read that is better to use `XF86Reload` instead

- https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10751
- https://blogs.gnome.org/sudaltsov/2008/12/24/consolidation/

You should try and test if that helps you, looks like it was a consolidation a while ago

Comment: Editing keymappings is a necessary hoop to jump through for us folks on chromebooks with non-standard keyboards. The short version is you edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`. If you want to see exactly what I did, I forked a repo and edited the script for my purposes on my [github](https://github.com/knorquist/CBFixesAndTweaks).

As far as why use `XF86Refresh`, it worked fine a few weeks ago and works as expected in any other browser besides Chrome, so I don't know what the issue is, but I'll give `XF86Reload` a try and see if that works!

Comment: Is this the keyboard? https://i.imgur.com/gtjfR0U.jpg , and the key is the "refresh" next to the "right arrow" on the top-left? I didn't knew they had different keyboards, never tried to see them in detail because wasn't interested in them :P

Comment: Yup, and that's the key I'm fiddling with. If you're willing to tinker, they can make excellent linux machines, and for a lot cheaper than regular laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Following what @Sebastian suggested, I remapped the key in question to `XF86Reload`. Reloading a page in Chrome works fine now, and still works in Epiphany, but broke in Firefox. Since I don't use Firefox too much, and since `CTRL + R` still works fine, this solution is workable for me.

Comment: try with https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/saka-key/ - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly or https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/ or maybe another... gl